# Pygame AttributeError: class User_Ship has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame, 2d-games

I am making a space invaders clone and I'm having some trouble. So right now I have the user controlled ship (currently a mouse because that's what I had in my python folder from a previous game, but I will change that eventually) moving back and forth at the bottom of the screen which is what I want, but I'm having trouble having it shoot when I press the space bar. I can start up the game, but when I press the space bar, I get this error:

AttributeError: class User_Ship has no attribute 'rect'

and I don't know how to fix it. Also, I think once that is fixed, my ship still won't shoot because I had a hard time getting the code down, so there are probably some errors. If you could give me some hints and tips to get my ship to shoot, that would be great. Thanks

```
from pygame import *
import pygame

size_x = 900
size_y = 650

class Object:
    def disp(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.sprite, self.rect)

class User_Ship(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sprite = image.load("mouse.bmp")
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = size_x/2
        self.rect.centery = size_y - 40
        self.count = 0
        self.move_x = 0
        self.move_y = 0

    def checkwith(self, otherrect):
        if self.rect.colliderect(otherrect):
            exit()

    def cycle(self):
        self.rect.centerx += self.move_x
        if self.rect.centerx < 0:
            self.rect.centerx = 0
        if self.rect.centerx > size_x:
            self.rect.centerx = size_x

        self.rect.centery += self.move_y
        if self.rect.centery < 0:
            self.rect.centery = 800

    def right(self):
        self.move_x += 10

    def left(self):
        self.move_x -= 10

    def stop_x(self):
        self.move_x = 0

    def stop_y(self):
        self.move_y = 0

class Missile(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sprite = image.load("missile.png")
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed)
        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > size_x or self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.bottom > size_y:
            self.kill()

missiles = pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates()


init()
screen = display.set_mode((size_x, size_y))
m = User_Ship()
#b = Missile()
clock = time.Clock()

while True:
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            quit()
        if e.type == KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == K_RIGHT:
                m.right()
            elif e.key == K_LEFT:
                m.left()
            if (e.key == K_SPACE):
                missiles.add(Missile("missile.png",(User_Ship.rect.centerx)))
        if e.type == KEYUP:
            if e.key == K_RIGHT or e.key == K_LEFT:
                m.stop_x()

    missiles.draw(screen)
    m.cycle()
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    m.disp(screen)
#   b.disp(screen)
    display.flip()
```

Answer (score 3):

`rect` is not a class attribute but an instance attribute. So, you might want to access it like this

```
missiles.add(Missile("missile.png",(m.rect.centerx)))
```

Comment: This is awkward... removing my answer you beat me to it.